# feeding your cats when you’re on vacation?

Tags: cats, health

I have two cats: one’s an 8-year old middle-aged guy and the other’s a senior citizen gal. They eat dry food.

What do you do to feed them if you’re out of the house a few days?

Is there a reliable machine where I can control their food from *afar*?

I don’t want to leave them plates of dry cat food because I know they’ll throw up. Also, the food won’t be fresh.

I bought an [auto-feeder like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcRBS.jpg), but I don’t know if I should trust it.

Comment: A some kind of similar question (your own) from 2018 ^^ I wanted to find the linked post about a very smart cat and the owner who made a nearly undestroyable cover for the automated feeder ... 3rd comment under the original question : https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/23315/alternative-for-automatic-dry-cat-feeder

Answer (score 1):

**I suggest you buy something electronic.** I don't know they are remote accessible but they are timed. You can adjust the time and amount of food before you go.

This doesn't work too well. It gets jammed after a certain point so cats have to use their paws to drag more pieces. This is not terrible unless you have a very old cat with low enough appetite to not to bother with it. But, while cats try to pull the food forward they might just disassemble the dispenser spilling food all over.

Also, for three days, I suggest you ask a friend or a neighbour to drop down on day 2 if you can. This is not crucial if they are going along very well but a long separation might induce some anxiety which might result in some fights.

Comment: Speaking for myself here, even with automated feeders, I would want a remote-access camera set up to make sure the feeders are actually working properly, as well as the fountain you'll most likely want to set up too not being flipped over and spilled all over the floor. At that point, you might just as well ask someone to check in anyway.